# After a DocuSign envelope is Signed, what "processing" occurs before triggering the Completed event?

Tags: docusignapi

According to the [DocuSign documentation](https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-admin-guide/admin-guide/envelope-recipient-events-ref), the envelope status will move automatically from **Signed** to **Completed** after "processing":

> Signed: This event is sent when the envelope has been signed by all
>   required recipients. Note that this is a temporary state used during
>   processing, after which the envelope is automatically moved to
>   Completed status.

What does "processing" mean here, and about how long does it take?

Comment: To add to Mike's point here, "processing" means the system is scanning the rest of the envelope to see if this was the last recipient and if the whole envelope should therefore be moved into the completed state, but it also means the document is automatically being encrypted at very high standards (since it's your private data) but it's also being hashed (so that it's tamper proof)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the processing you refer to is the state in which DocuSign is preparing and making available the final documents for consumption.  Depending on their sizes this may take a little time. My documents which typically are about 10mb a piece, each envelope having 2 documents with an average of 3 signature fields 'processing' takes seconds.